# VB.net: Is there a way to get the Printed File Path from Printform?

Tags: vb.net, file, datagridview, filenames, email-attachments

im working on my first big program. I will try to explain short how the important part of the program works, and then try to explain what my problem is.

My program is used by few people, they drive around the Europe and repair our machines. After the work, they start my program, and write a report. Until now the program was generating at the end 3 Files. (PDF file generated by printform, text file which contained the same information's again and the last file that was an Excel file, that one contained Data that was written inside the Datagridview.
These workers, used Email to send all 3 files separated. As you imagine, sometimes that can end bad, cause after work they are tired and sometimes they send the wrong files. So I made a upgrade, which gives the user a possibility to send the files directly from the Program, being sure everything is fine. In background I created a directory where 2 of 3 files always get saved. The problem is, while using printform, there opens a window where the user can select the path. And here start the troubles, some of the workers select different a different path, but then my program wont find the files again(its very important that are 3 files are together). I searched for something that would look like

```
dim printformpath as string = printform.getpath
```

is there something that works that way? I was searching but I didn't found anything helpful.
Thank you for understanding & help

Comment: If you set PrintFileName property it apparently won't ask the user where to put it. Ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629268.aspx

Comment: Thinking about it though, that may not help as you're printing to PDF which means you must be selecting a printer driver rather than printing to a file. Maybe something like https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ would help?

Comment: Have you thought (and tried) about choosing printer by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I added the path to the printFileName property and changed printform settings from Print to preview to print to file :)
Have a nice day